# Python - Module not found for a dependent project while launching flask

Tags: python, flask, module, python-import, python-wheel

My flask project structure looks like this:

```
flask_demo_app
-app
    -__init__.py
    -routes.py
-demoapp_venv
-flask_demo_app.py
```

My **init**.py looks like this :

```
    from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes
```

code inside flask_demo_app.py

```
from app import app
```

code inside routes.py:

```
    import os
cwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print(cwd)
from app import app
from flask import render_template
from mySDK_python_sdk.mySDK_core import core_config


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return 'Hello world'


@app.route('/sdk')
def test_sdk1():
    print('invoking from rutes')
    config = core_config.RestClientConfig('194.138.0.25', '9400')
    return config
```

mySDK project is my another python project which is installed as a wheel file and available inside demoapp_venv/site-packages. When i run routes.py directly without using flask (of course removing "@app.route"), it invokes the methods inside "core_config" as expected. But when I run flask run command, it gives me module not found error for the modules of the installed "mySDK" project. 
I am using pycharm editor and marked the installed packages of mySDK as "source root".

Please let me know why I am getting module not found error for installed app.